# swift google maps will not show snippet window

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

for some odd reason when a marker is tapped google map will not show the snippet window in my swift code. I just dont see what im doing wrong. I get the marker on the map but when i tap it it does not show anything. Thank you in advance.

```
 func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        let position = place.coordinate



          self.dismiss(animated: true) {
                let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
                marker.title = "title here"
                marker.snippet = "my snippet here"

                marker.map = self.mapView

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to remove the delegate below in order for the infowindow to show.

```
//    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
//        print("marker Tapped")
//
//        return true
//    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put in the delegate

```
mapView.selectedMarker = marker
```

so the code will be as this :

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    print("marker Tapped")
     mapView.selectedMarker = marker 
    return true
}
```

Hope this will help you.